# Unable to locate element using xpath in headless Chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, whatsapp

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am currently working on a Python script using Selenium to automate sending an image via WhatsApp Web in headless Chrome. However, I am encountering an error with locating an element using xpath. Here's the error message I am receiving:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div/span[@title='Bookmark']"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=113.0.5672.92)
```

I am trying to select a chat in WhatsApp Web by locating an element with the xpath //div/span[@title='Bookmark']. The script works fine when I run it in non-headless mode, but when I switch to headless mode, it seems like Selenium is unable to locate the element.

I have tried adding explicit waits and a delay before trying to locate the element, but I am still encountering the same error. I have also confirmed that the xpath I am using is correct by inspecting the page manually.

Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
chat_name = "Bookmark"  
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div/span[@title='Bookmark']")
```

I am using headless Chrome version 113.0.5672.92 and the latest version of Selenium. Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue

```
import requests 
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# Set up Chrome options to run in headless mode
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

# Launch Chrome browser and navigate to WhatsApp Web 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")

# Select the chat or group
chat_name = "Bookmark"  
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div/span[@title='Bookmark']")

search_box.send_keys(chat_name)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)  # Make sure chat opens

# Attach and send the image
attachment_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@title, 'Attach')]")
attachment_box.click()

time.sleep(2)  # wait for the file dialog to open

upload_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
upload_button.send_keys("/Users/rajeevranjanpandey/Desktop/Screenshot 2023-04-11 at 3.44.43 PM.png")

time.sleep(10)  # wait for the image to upload  

# Send the image
send_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@data-icon='send']")
send_button.click()  

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

I have tried:

Updating the XPath selector after re-inspecting the page
Using CSS selectors instead of XPath
Running without the --headless arg
Adding time.sleep(10) after navigating to page
But I'm still unable to locate the element. WhatsApp Web seems to have made major changes, and my traditional methods aren't working.

How can I fix this and get my script working again? Any help is greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need any more information from me.

Comment: Any  help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the line:

```
search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div/span[@title='Bookmark']")
```

To:

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='Bookmark']")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried earlier what you mentioned but getting the below Error
Traceback (most recent call last):

    search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//span[@title='Bookmark']")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Comment: Try it:
WebDriverWait(drive, timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, ''))
        )

Comment: Getting the below error even I imported the Webdrive module


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


    search_box = WebDriverWait(drive, timeout).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '')) )
NameError: name 'drive' is not defined

Comment: i have tried other ways 
# Select the chat or group
chat_name = "Bookmark"
timeout = 20  # Define the timeout value (in seconds)
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.title_contains("WhatsApp"))
#search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div/span[@title='" + chat_name + "']")))
search_box = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='" + chat_name + "']")))[0]


but no luck .